# Remove list item that starts with a character followed by some value

Tags: python, list

I'm iterating through a lot of folders and extracting the names of the folders, as I am to use it later on. However, most folders has some weird words in it that I don't need for later use. So for example a folder name could be `930_930_MRTY_2018-30-04_091_FIX_F.42_n1__00001`. And that is how most folder names are. So if I use `split("_")` I can separate these strings a bit. But, the one thing I don't need for further use is the `n##` string.

So for this I can just use the following:

```
filter_words = [".", "", "n1"]
folder_name_info = [word for word in y.split("_") if word not in filter_words]
```

to get the list without the stuff I don't like. For this example, this correctly removes the `n1` from the list, but the case is that it's pretty random which number is after the `n`. So how would I go around it to target all strings that starts with `n` followed by any number ?

Comment: you can use regex

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super good yet with regex operations, but a way around it would be this:

```
import re

filter_words = [".", ""]
folder_name_info = [word for word in y.split("_")
                      if (word not in filter_words and
                          not re.search('^n[1-9]')]
```

Here `'^n[1-9]'` means a string starting with an n followed by any number. You can also check the [documentation on regex](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) to get an idea of how to use them.